# Spring Security + Mock MVC Testing - Assertion error, redirect URL "http://localhost/login" instead of "/login"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, mockmvc

I have such a test

```java
@Test
@WithAnonymousUser
void givenNoAuthentication_whenEnteringMainPage_thenRedirectToLoginPage() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(redirectedUrl("/login"));
}
```

And I got assertion error like this:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Redirected URL expected:</login> but was:<http://localhost/login>
Expected :/login
Actual   :http://localhost/login
```

What is more, I have another test similar to this one which tests if logged in user gets redirected to main page ("/") after accessing /login and this test is working fine

```java
@Test
@WithMockUser
void givenAuthentication_whenEnteringLoginPage_thenRedirectToMainPage() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/login")).andExpect(redirectedUrl("/"));
}
```

Here is how my spring security config looks like

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize - > authorize
                .requestMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/user/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin(form - > form
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)

            )
            .logout(logout - > logout
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            )
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

How can I fix my first test, and why it doesnt't work when second test which is almost the same is working fine?

EDIT:
I managed to fix this by using `.endsWith("/login")` like so

```java
MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andReturn();
assertThat(result.getResponse().getRedirectedUrl()).endsWith("/login");
```

But I still don't understand why in this test redirect url contains hostname, and it other it doesn't

Comment: Despite the test failure, does your spring application work as expected? Does it redirects to `/login` if `/` entered?

Comment: Yes it works as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not a definitive answer, maybe my research will help someone as this behavior is a bit annoying when writing tests for `/login`, because that endpoint behaves differently.

There are some related answers:

- [JUnit Test a Controller View with Spring Security throws java.lang.AssertionError: No ModelAndView found after HTTP Status 302](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74013075/junit-test-a-controller-view-with-spring-security-throws-java-lang-assertionerro) - see the authors comment on accepted answer
- [Spring Security is redirecting to localhost on production server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884850/spring-security-is-redirecting-to-localhost-on-production-server) - related slightly

I believe the behavior is intentional for two reasons

1. The behavior only occurs on `/login` and no other endpoints. `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.buildRedirectUrlToLoginPage` is responsible for this behavior, there is explicit logic that makes the URL absolute (`spring.security.web:6.2.1`):

```
if (UrlUtils.isAbsoluteUrl(loginForm)) {
    return loginForm;
}
// ...
// otherwise construct absolute URL
```

2. [FormLoginConfigurerTests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/config/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/FormLoginConfigurerTests.java) has asserts for `redirectedUrl` for login set explicitly to test absolute values everywhere. On all other places the tests uses relative paths.

### Speculations only:

Maybe it's a bug or was written in that way due to historical reasons - e.g. older [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) stated to use absolute uris:

> Location       = "Location" ":" absoluteURI

but the newer [RFC 7231](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231) allows relative paths (details [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25643550/11130394)).

Or maybe there is some security concern in mind - forcing to use absolute URI on login so that app have "more" under control whether `http` or `https` is used.

Either way, I haven't found a way to configure it to behave differently. So right now I'm forced to test `/login` endpoints differently than other endpoints.

Comment: How do you test `/login` endpoints then? Did you find something more accurate and universal than `.endsWith()`? Is it okay to use it, or should I use something else?

Comment: I'm following the authors and using full url everywhere (`redirectedUrl("http://localhost/login")`) as endsWith would also succeed if app redirected to `/someOtherUrl/login`. But I guess `endsWith` is not that bad too.

Comment: But what if we deploy our app on a hosting ie "example.com"? Wouldn't `http://localhost/login` then become `http://example.com/login` and tests will fail?

Comment: I don't think I get the last question - even if you deploy the site to `example.com`, you're still running mockmvc tests locally (or as part of pipeline, but still "locally" from test POV) and there you'd still get redirected to `localhost`. If you don't plan to have `/login` page on different site than rest of the site, I would just use `localhost` asserts in tests. But your proposed solution with `endsWith` is also fine.